# Time complexity of Sudoko solver and relation to NP-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, sudoku, np-complete

Basically I am confused as to what "the general problem of solving N×N Sudoku puzzles is NP-complete" really means.
Does it mean that if I have an algorithm which takes a NxN Sudoku board as input and solves it the algorithm must be exponential in time complexity with regards to N?
Or is "the general problem" finding ALL NxN Sudoku boards which are valid puzzles?

The reason I am asking is because I have an algorithm which solves an NxN Sudoku board in polynomial time, thus I am confused as to what "the general problem of Sudoku" really means.

The algorithm itself is rather simple, treat all the positions on the NxN sudoku board as unknown variables (thus we have N^2 variables), then set up a system of equations for all those variables, write it in matrix form we get a N^2 by 3N matrix with only ones and zeros, representing which positions should be added together for the rows,columns and boxes in the sudoku puzzle. Now we have the sudoku problem on the form A*x = b, where A is our large matrix, x is the vector we want to find and b is a vector with the sum of all values (for example 45 on a 9x9 sudoku board).
Instead of representing the values on the sudoku board with numbers (for example 1 to 9) they are represented with a one-hot encoding (so 4 is [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0] etc). Thus x and b in the equation becomes "vectors of vectors" (Note, NOT a matrix, we still treat A*x as if x was scalar, so each element in A scales a whole vector in x, so not matrix multiplication).
the b vector becomes the sum of all one-hot encoding vectors, i.e a vector with only ones.

Now we just account for the known values on the sudoku board by setting the elements in the A matrix which correspond to the known board position to zero and subtract the value (one-hot encoding) in the b vector. Then we just use Gauss elimination to solve the system, thus we can still treat the one-hot encodings in the b vector as scalars which are just being added/subtracted and scaled.
Once we have completed the gauss elimination we are left with the solution in the b-vector. Since the sudoku is unique we should have just one solution, and because of the one-hot encoding we can also check if a sudoku is valid, since if the b-vector contains anything but 1's and 0's it is not a valid puzzle. The gauss elimination also tells us if there are multiple or no solutions since the last rows will be completely 0 or 0 = 1 for no solutions. Another benefit of the one-hot encoding is that you can easily find the solution when the system is underdetermined. Since you know all x values only have a single one it eliminates many possible solutions. Consider the case where the A matrix has a row of [3,1,2,0,0,0] and the corresponding b-value is [0,0,2,0,3,1]. Then you know that the 3, 2 and 1 all pair up, since it is the only way you can get this result using one-hot encoded values on x. The same principle can be used to quickly solve which x correspond to which b value when you have an underdetermined A matrix with only ones and zeros.

Gauss elimination is cubic in time complexity in regard to the size of the matrix, the size of the matrix is N^2 with regards to the sudoku board size, this the algorithm gets a time complexity of N^6 with regard to the board size.

I have very likely overlooked something or misunderstood the NP-completeness of the general sudoku problem, but that's why I'm asking this question :)

Comment: the fact that you can solve it in polynomial time for some specific size of a grid does not mean you can solve it that way for all grid sizes

Comment: @mangusta So you're saying my algorithm won't work for larger boards?
Or do you mean that I would need an algorithm which solved all board sizes in the same polynomial time?

Comment: if the size of a board is a variable (not static), it has to be considered in the complexity. the complexity of your algorithm might be polynomial if you ignore the size of a board

Comment: @mangusta But the size of the board is a variable. I can give it a 3x3 board, or a 2x2 board, or 100x100 board and it solves them in polynomial time with regard to the board size. I feel like I've misunderstood something here :S

Comment: are you sure that your algorithm solves it in polynomial time regardless of size?

Comment: @mangusta What do you mean by "regardless of size". The time complexity of the algorithm is O(N^6) where N is the board size I put into the algorithm. So larger boards obviously go slower, but from my understanding it's still polynomial and not exponential? Also, I'm still testing the algorithm, so I am not sure right now. This is mostly based on how it works "on paper".

Comment: why don't you post your algorithm here so that the users could verify its polynomial runtime

Comment: @mangusta Ok, it's a fairly naive algorithm, so I am sure I must have made a misstake somewhere (Hence my confusion). I'll put the algorithm in the question.

Comment: it is clear that you would like to represent the problem as a set of linear equations. a bit unclear how the matrix is represented. we have N^2 unknowns x11, x12,..., xnn (represented by 0-1 vectors). we also have N equations for rows, N equations for columns and N equations for boxes. Could you show an example of how the equations for the sudoku row [5, _ , 6, 3, 1, _ , 8, _ , _ ] would look like (assume it is the very first row)

Comment: you may skip the equations for columns and boxes because they are incomplete with just a single row

Comment: every equation in the system of linear equations should have the same set of unknowns. also, with K unknowns the number of equations should be at least K to have a unique solution. however in sudoku, N rows, N columns and N boxes are 3N total (number of equations) which is less than N^2 (number of unknowns). secondly, let's for example take 1st row. Its equation must have non-zero values for x11,x12..,x1n and all zeros for x21,x22,..,xnn for the sum to be equal to 45. But x21,x22,..,xnn cannot be zero because they are used in other rows/columns/boxes. IMHO we can't solve it by linear equation

Comment: @mangusta For the exampme, the A matrix would be [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1] and then the rest zeros (assuming a 9 by 9 that would be another 71 zeros). The corresponding b value would be [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]. The reason you can still solve it even if you have an underdetermined system is that you know your solution consist of one-hot encodings. Also, the known values in the sudoku is actually an equation. Also, it does work at least for 4 by 4 and 9 by 9 sudokus, so it’s not like we can’t solve it using linear equations.

Comment: ah, I was wrong when suggesting that x21,x22,..,xnn should be zero, they actually should not. It is coefficients that are equal to zero, which makes the sum equal to 45. Well I didn't investigate that one-hot encoding further, in case if it is indeed possible to solve underdetermined system by means of it, then your solution seems to be correct

Comment: But if it is correct then the problem is P hard, thus proving that P=NP which is extremely unlikely :/ so either the solution is wrong or I am confused about something about NP-completeness :s

Comment: if N=9, number of unknowns is 81. number of row/column/box equations is 3×9=27. If number of known values is at least 81-27=54 then number of unknowns and total number of equations is same and the problem can be solved by system of linear equations. If it is below 54, I'm sceptical about linear equation solution even if one-hot encoding is used. Personally I have never seen sudoku game given with at least 54 known values, that would be too easy)

Comment: You’re right, I probably have to look into the robustness of solving the system using the one hot representation more. It will probably turn out it can’t be solved for all sudoku boards

Comment: Does the system of equations guarantee the uniqueness of each element within a row/column/box?  I think it does not, that's where the problem is. We can solve the equation but we cannot guarantee that the values from 1 to 9 will all appear within a row/column/box

Comment: The system of equations would be helpful if we could fill the cell with any number. We cannot guarantee uniqueness, that goes beyond the linear equation and makes it closer to the integer linear programming model where we have additional constraints for variables x11,..,xnn. Integer linear programming problem is NP-complete

Comment: @mangusta The uniqueness of each element within a row/column/box is guaranteed if all the x-values are on the form [1,0,0,0...] (i.e. a vector with only a single one in it) since the only way to get [1,1,1,1,1,1...] when you sum them up in each row/column/box is to have one of each. Of course solving the system itself does not guarantee that you will get x with only ones, hence why you need to check your answer. This is where I think the exponential time complexity comes in, I have assumed it can be done in polynomial time and I've only worked on small boards.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake in my algorithm when it comes to getting the x. I had only tried it on small sudoku where the problem reduced to a 2-SAT problem and thus I wrongly made the assumption that it would be a 2-SAT problem for larger sudoku too, however it quickly turned into a 3-SAT or even bigger.